# Having a popup menu show/create a dialog box? Windows32 programming

Tags: c, winapi, dialog, popupmenu

I've looked at MSDN for about 2 hours so far and I'm still very confused as to how to even use a dialog box. I've tried reading several examples on google and just got confused further.

Currently I have a popup menu that has its options just being checked and unchecked and the last item I have on the menu is to make a dialog box show, inside the dialogbox I'm going to have a group box for some radio buttons but I'm **unsure of where to create a dialog box or what kind of dialog box to create to be shown by the popup menu.**
Is it made in the WM_CREATE message I thought it might be as simple as creating a window bu it doesn't seem like it? 
or is it made in the WM_COMMAND where I trigger my popup menu item.
**The case ID_TOOL_TOOLBOX is where the dialog box should be called to be shown or created. But I'm not sure whether its to be created there or even what kind of dialogbox to make.**

Or somewhere else different entirely?

```
case WM_COMMAND:

    case ID_TOOL_POLYGON:
        CheckMenuItem(hMenu, Selection, MF_UNCHECKED);
        Selection = LOWORD(wParam);
        CheckMenuItem(hMenu, Selection, MF_CHECKED);
        if (GetMenuState(hMenu, Selection, MF_BYCOMMAND) == MF_CHECKED)
        {
                MessageBox(hwnd, L"Polygon does nothing this is a test popup msgbox.", L"Works", MB_OK);
        }
        break;

    case ID_TOOL_SELECT:
        CheckMenuItem(hMenu, Selection, MF_UNCHECKED);
        Selection = LOWORD(wParam);
        CheckMenuItem(hMenu, Selection, MF_CHECKED);
        break;

    case ID_TOOL_TOOLBOX:
```

Comment: Do you want a "canned", pre-defined message box with your string and 1 to three buttons? Or do you want a custom dialog box created from a window description in resources, such as settings dialog?

Comment: @Arkadiy a dialog box specifically for interaction, not a message box. the dialog box will have like a grouped box of like maybe 1-4 radio buttons in it, ty for the link i didnt come across that :(. Yes it will sort of be like a settings dialog! It will toggle on certain functions the program im writing is just trying to draw some shapes and the dialog will help accomplish switchign between them using radio buttons

Comment: In that case you need to prepare the template using dialog editor and then follow the tutorial below to show the template on screen as dialog.

Comment: i got it working now thanks! in my ID_TOOL_TOOLBOX i just added a ShowWindow(hdialogbox, SW_SHOW); after creating it in the winmain from the link you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the first hits that shows up when we search for "win32 ShowDialog":

http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson04.htm

> A dialog box is created using the DialogBox function. Its syntax is:
>
> INT_PTR DialogBox(HINSTANCE hInstance, LPCTSTR lpTemplate, HWND
>   hWndParent, DLGPROC lpDialogFunc);
>
> The first argument of this function is a handle to the application
>   that is using the dialog box.
>
> The lpTemplate specifies the dialog box template.
>
> The hWndParent is a handle to the parent window that owns this dialog
>   box.
>
> The lpDialofFunc must a procedure that is in charge of creating this
>   dialog box.
>
> Therefore, you must define a CALLBACK procedure that whose syntax is:
>
> INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
>   LPARAM lParam);